# Spring Reactor Web Client use case. replacing RestTemplate with WebClient

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, project-reactor

I am working on a microservice project where my individual spring boot microservices would be calling themselves and mainly to 3rd party API's to fetch and save data.

Since I am with legacy Spring boot application I can't think of replacing it with Reactor based Microservices.

But I am thinking of replacing My RestTemplate (using for communication with Other MS's and 3rd Party App) with new Spring Reactor Webclient to get some advantages of Async calls.
Is My use case a right candidate for Using Spring reactor WebClient?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, composition of microservice and REST calls is a good use case for `WebClient`.

Plus Spring Boot 2 will let you combine the Spring MVC starter with the WebFlux starter and interpret that as "you want to run on the servlet stack, but might want to use `WebClient` sporadically".